# How to fix not running presto plugin in AWS EMR

Tags: plugins, emr, presto

### About

I'm trying to use presto plugin like wyukawa/presto-fluentd, it works on localhost(mac os x), but does not work on Amazon EMR.

### Detail

#### on localhost

At first, I tried to work on localhost(mac os x) and just it works.

- plugin dir

  ```
  reizist ...plugin/presto-fluentd $ pwd
  /usr/local/Cellar/presto/0.185/libexec/plugin/presto-fluentd
  reizist ...plugin/presto-fluentd $ ls -1
  fluency-1.3.0.jar
  guava-21.0.jar
  jackson-annotations-2.8.1.jar
  jackson-core-2.7.1.jar
  jackson-databind-2.7.1.jar
  jackson-dataformat-msgpack-0.8.12.jar
  jolokia-jvm-1.3.7-agent.jar
  log-0.148.jar
  msgpack-core-0.8.12.jar
  phi-accural-failure-detector-0.0.4.jar
  presto-fluentd-0.0.1.jar
  slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar
  ```
- properties

  ```
  reizist ...libexec/etc $ pwd
  /usr/local/Cellar/presto/0.185/libexec/etc
  reizist ...libexec/etc $ ls -1
  catalog
  config.properties
  event-listener.properties
  jvm.config
  log.properties
  node.properties
  reizist ...libexec/etc $ cat event-listener.properties
  event-listener.name=presto-fluentd
  event-listener.fluentd-host=localhost
  event-listener.fluentd-port=24224
  event-listener.fluentd-tag=presto.query
  ```

[left: presto log, center: fluentd log, right: presto-cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMnfy.png)

#### on EMR

Also I tried same on EC2 on EMR, but it did not work.
[That plugin is correctly loaded, event listener registered](https://gist.github.com/reizist/d943cd54dee635213ad7d791aedf31cc#file-gistfile1-txt-L409), so I feel strange.

- plugin dir

  ```
  [hadoop@ip-172-31-29-54 plugin]$ pwd
  /usr/lib/presto/plugin
  [hadoop@ip-172-31-29-54 plugin]$ ls
  accumulo   cassandra     jmx        memory   mysql           redis                    tpch
  atop       example-http  kafka      ml       postgresql      resource-group-managers
  blackhole  hive-hadoop2  localfile  mongodb  presto-fluentd  teradata-functions
  [hadoop@ip-172-31-29-54 plugin]$ ls -1 presto-fluentd/
  fluency-1.3.0.jar
  guava-21.0.jar
  jackson-annotations-2.8.1.jar
  jackson-core-2.7.1.jar
  jackson-databind-2.7.1.jar
  jackson-dataformat-msgpack-0.8.12.jar
  log-0.148.jar
  msgpack-core-0.8.12.jar
  phi-accural-failure-detector-0.0.4.jar
  presto-fluentd-0.0.1.jar
  slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar
  ```
- properties

  ```
  [hadoop@ip-172-31-29-54 presto]$ pwd
  /etc/presto
  [hadoop@ip-172-31-29-54 presto]$ tree .
  .
  ├── conf -> /etc/alternatives/presto-conf
  ├── conf.dist
  │   ├── catalog
  │   │   ├── hive.properties
  │   │   └── mysql.properties
  │   ├── config.properties
  │   ├── jvm.config
  │   ├── log.properties
  │   ├── node.properties
  │   └── presto-env.sh
  └── event-listener.properties

  3 directories, 8 files
  [hadoop@ip-172-31-29-54 presto]$ cat event-listener.properties
  event-listener.name=presto-fluentd
  event-listener.fluentd-host=localhost
  event-listener.fluentd-port=24224
  event-listener.fluentd-tag=presto.query
  ```

I also tested by inserting print debugging code, but it looks like not loaded.
How I should to work this plugin on EMR?

Thanks.

### supplement

here is the fluentd configuration.

```
<source>
  @type forward
</source>

<match *.**>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

Comment: I noticed that ec2 on emr log does not output ` loaded event listener presto-fluentd ` , so maybe something is wrong in my configuration. https://gist.github.com/reizist/b1a07d6326c48b5ecfaa9aec62182188

Comment: according to https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/6e7c9ca25cfc7940c961638fbc06b692b7b869c0/presto-main/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/eventlistener/EventListenerManager.java#L62 , event-listener.properties have to be located on ` etc/ ` dir, but actually I locate event-listener.properties on ` /etc/presto ` , is this wrong? if so, where is the dir ... I'm going to try to locate ` event-listener.properties on /etc/presto/conf `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by my own.

Actually I have to locate `event-listener.properties` on `/mnt/var/lib/presto/data/etc` , so I did this:

```
$s3uri="s3://my-s3-bucket"

# make symbolic link
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/presto/etc
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/presto/etc /mnt/var/lib/presto/data

# download presto plugins
aws s3 sync $s3uri/jar/ /usr/lib/presto/plugin/
aws s3 sync $s3uri/properties/ /usr/lib/presto/etc/

# make sure all plugins are owned by presto user
chown -R presto:presto /usr/lib/presto/plugin
chown -R presto:presto /usr/lib/presto/etc


# restart presto
stop  presto-server
start presto-server
```

finally my dir is like below:

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-21-25 presto]$ pwd
/usr/lib/presto
[hadoop@ip-172-31-21-25 presto]$ ls -alh
total 228K
drwxr-xr-x  7 root   root   4.0K Oct 19 06:52 .
dr-xr-xr-x 47 root   root   4.0K Oct 19 06:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 presto presto 4.0K Oct 19 06:30 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 presto presto 4.0K Oct 19 06:52 etc
drwxr-xr-x  2 presto presto  12K Oct 19 06:30 lib
-rw-r--r--  1 presto presto 188K Sep 22 22:54 NOTICE
drwxr-xr-x 24 presto presto 4.0K Oct 19 06:45 plugin
drwxr-xr-x  2 presto presto 4.0K Oct 19 06:30 presto-jdbc
-rw-r--r--  1 presto presto  119 Sep 22 22:54 README.txt

[hadoop@ip-172-31-21-25 etc]$ pwd
/usr/lib/presto/etc
[hadoop@ip-172-31-21-25 etc]$ ls
event-listener.properties

[hadoop@ip-172-31-21-25 plugin]$ pwd
/usr/lib/presto/plugin
[hadoop@ip-172-31-21-25 plugin]$ ls
accumulo   example-http  localfile  mysql           redis                    tpcds
atop       hive-hadoop2  memory     postgresql      resource-group-managers  tpch
blackhole  jmx           ml         presto-fluentd  sqlserver
cassandra  kafka         mongodb    presto-thrift   teradata-functions
```

and it works correctly.

Comment: Any help here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286733/logging-all-presto-queries

Comment: Okay currently I'm collecting presto all query, so maybe I can advise to you