# Logging all presto queries

Tags: java, maven, bigdata, presto

How can I store all queries submitted to presto cluster in a file (ORC file) or may be some other database. Purpose is the keep the record of all queries executed on presto workers.

I am aware that I need to overwrite queryCompleted method, I have also tried to follow [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/9jV7iOfdqeY) and other link mentioned over there but I am unable to create correct jar using maven. After placing the presto jar file generated by maven, my presto stopped working.

I am new to presto as well as in maven. It would be great if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is my way, and It works on EMR5.9 (presto 0.184).

Firstly, as you already know, you can use event-listener.
In my case, I use https://github.com/wyukawa/presto-fluentd for collecting query logs because fluentd is convenient.(easy to retry, easy to send 
 to multiple data store)
if you want to create new event-listener plugin, also you can reference this because it's very simple. (or https://github.com/zz22394/presto-audit can also use for it)

Next, you have to install event-listener plugin.
If you use EMR, you can use this script for installing `presto-fluentd` on [bootstrap actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html)

```
# cf. https://github.com/mozilla/emr-bootstrap-presto/blob/master/files/bootstrap/presto-plugins.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -exo pipefail

# re-exec with sudo into background
if [ $(whoami) != root ]; then
  sudo "$0" "$@" &
  exit 0
fi

# set variables
s3uri=$1
fluentd_endpoint=$2

# wait until presto is installed and running
until test -s /var/run/presto/presto-server.pid; do sleep 1; done

# make symbolic link
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/presto/etc 2>/dev/null
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/presto/etc /mnt/var/lib/presto/data

# download presto plugins
aws s3 sync $s3uri/jar/ /usr/lib/presto/plugin/
aws s3 sync $s3uri/properties /usr/lib/presto/etc/

# make sure all plugins are owned by presto user
chown -R presto:presto /usr/lib/presto/plugin
chown -R presto:presto /usr/lib/presto/etc

# set event-listner.properties endpoint parameter
echo "event-listener.fluentd-host=$fluentd_endpoint" >> 
/usr/lib/presto/etc/event-listener.properties

# restart presto
stop  presto-server
start presto-server
```

event-listener.properties:

```
event-listener.name=presto-fluentd
event-listener.fluentd-port=24224
event-listener.fluentd-tag=presto.query
```

inside s3 dir:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://<s3 bucket>/emr/bootstrap_actions/plugins/jar/presto-fluentd/
2017-10-30 19:12:59      90318 fluency-1.3.0.jar
2017-10-30 19:12:59    2521113 guava-21.0.jar
2017-10-30 19:12:59      55783 jackson-annotations-2.8.1.jar
2017-10-30 19:12:59     252303 jackson-core-2.7.1.jar
2017-10-30 19:12:59    1199160 jackson-databind-2.7.1.jar
2017-10-30 19:12:59      30488 jackson-dataformat-msgpack-0.8.12.jar
2017-10-30 19:12:59       3907 log-0.148.jar
2017-10-30 19:12:59     116125 msgpack-core-0.8.12.jar
2017-10-30 19:12:59       5509 phi-accural-failure-detector-0.0.4.jar
2017-10-30 19:12:59       6130 presto-fluentd-0.0.1.jar
2017-10-30 19:12:59      41077 slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar

$ aws s3 ls s3://<s3 bucket>/emr/bootstrap_actions/plugins/properties/
2017-10-30 19:12:59        109 event-listener.properties
```

and just receive query logs by fluentd working on another host like below

```
<match presto.query>
  @type copy
  <store>
    # another data store
  </store>

  <store>
    @type relabel
    @label @presto-query-storage
  </store>
</match>

# In my case, I use bigquery for storing query log
<label @presto-query-storage>
  <match **>
    @label @presto-bigquery-out
    @type record_reformer
    renew_record true
    tag presto.query_storage.big_query
    <record>
      query_id ${record["queryId"]}
      user_name ${record["user"]}
      elapsed_time ${(record["endTime"] - record["createTime"]) / 1000.0}
      start_at 
${Time.at(record["executionStartTime"]/1000).utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N")}
      end_at ${Time.at(record["endTime"]/1000).utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
      query ${record["query"]}
      status ${record["state"]}
    </record>
  </match>
</label>
```

### Tips

I use this script for collecting dependencies of presto-fluentd.

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'open3'
include FileUtils

TMP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../tmp', __FILE__)
JAR_PATH = File.expand_path('../bootstrap_actions/plugins/jar', __FILE__)
CLONE_URI = 'https://github.com/wyukawa/presto-fluentd'

NEEDED_JAR = %w(
  fluency-1.3.0.jar
  guava-21.0.jar
  jackson-annotations-2.8.1.jar
  jackson-core-2.7.1.jar
  jackson-databind-2.7.1.jar
  jackson-dataformat-msgpack-0.8.12.jar
  log-0.148.jar
  msgpack-core-0.8.12.jar
  phi-accural-failure-detector-0.0.4.jar
  presto-fluentd-0.0.1.jar
  slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar
)

def cleanup_dir
  puts "Clean up #{TMP_PATH}/presto-fluentd ..."
  rm_r(Dir.glob("#{TMP_PATH}/presto-fluentd"))
  mkdir_p("#{JAR_PATH}/presto-fluentd")

  puts "Clean up #{JAR_PATH}/presto-fluentd ..."
  rm(Dir.glob("#{JAR_PATH}/presto-fluentd/*.jar"))
end

def clone
  cd(TMP_PATH)

  puts "Download presto-fluentd repo ..."
  out, err, status = Open3.capture2("git clone #{CLONE_URI} #{TMP_PATH}/presto-fluentd")
  puts out
end

def mvn
  cd("#{TMP_PATH}/presto-fluentd")

  puts "Build presto-fluentd ..."
  out, err, status = Open3.capture2("mvn clean package")
  puts out

  out, err, status = Open3.capture2("mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target -DincludeScope=runtime")
  puts out
end

def copy_dependencies
  cd("#{TMP_PATH}/presto-fluentd/target")
  puts "Copy jar files to #{JAR_PATH} ..."

  # FIXME: it's better to fix actual pom.xml for assign scope
  mv(Dir.glob("*.jar").select{|file| NEEDED_JAR.include?(file)}, "#{JAR_PATH}/presto-fluentd")
  puts "done !!"
end


cleanup_dir
clone
mvn
copy_dependencies
```

Comment: do you have a list of information querycreated and querycompleted objects return? I was trying to get the same using reflection api but got stuck now.

Comment: sorry, I don't know what do you want to know.. 
if you write down your situation details(presto version, dir structure, launcher log, and server environment(on aws or your localhost), maybe the problem become clear.
(FYI: firstly I tested presto-fluentd on local, and compare launcher logs between on AWS(failed situation) and on local(success situation) like this: https://gist.github.com/reizist/b1a07d6326c48b5ecfaa9aec62182188

Comment: I tried to obtain all fields and method associated with queryCompletedEvent object.          

Class<?> clazz = queryCompletedEvent.getMetadata().getClass();
         for(Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            writer.append(field.getName()+"\r\n ");
         }

This gives me fields of this object. But I need all nested objects as well. 
For example: queryCompletedEvent.getFailureInfo().get(); has further details, nested under it.

Comment: Can anyone please help me in making this work with a scenario where loki-fluentbit is deployed on kubernetes, and I need to fetch logs from another application running on another container on K8s but so far am unable to figure out what URL and port i should keep in event-listener.properties file in this case.